# Several content security policy (CSP) violations in Magento 2.4.5-p1 website. How to resolve them?

Tags: content-security-policy, magento2.4

Some weeks ago I noticed that our company's website (running Magento 2.4.5-p1) throws several CSP errors in the browser's console. As I am not a web dev, my understanding of coding is very limited, and haven't found any articles about this issue related to Magento 2.

While researching, I came across a business called Csper and using their free CSP policy evaluator I got a more detailed information about the errors. The report mentions that our policy uses the scripts 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' which they recommend not using because they can make the website vulnerable to XSS attacks.

So part of the suggestions of Csper are to remove these scripts, but at the same time they warn that this could require a refactoring of code. And here is my question: I am wondering if the CSP we have is a default Magento 2 script and if changing it could break something. If this is true, how could a default Magento script make the site vulnerable to XSS attacks?

And more importantly, how could I fix it? We currently use Google Analytics, Google Tag Manager and Facebook Ads as external services.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Update:

I will append one of the errors for further details about the issue:

```
[Report Only] Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src *.adobe.com *.sagepay.com *.fontawesome.com unsafe-inline *.trustpilot.com tagmanager.google.com 'self' 'unsafe-inline'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Please append the full error message and headers.

Comment: Hi Daniel, there are quite a lot of errors but I will try to append them to the post

Answer (score 2):

You can create csp_whitelist.xml file in etc folder, i.e.

`app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/etc/csp_whitelist.xml`

You can add a domain to the whitelist for a policy like script-src, style-src, font-src and others by adding a csp_whitelist.xml to your custom module’s etc folder.

```
<? xml version = "1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp/etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
   <policies>
      <policy id="script-src">
         <values>
             <value id="uniqueId" type="host">example.com</value>
             <value id="uniqueId" type="host">accounts.google.com</value>
          </values>
       </policy>
 </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```

this is more or less excessively described in the [docs](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/security/content-security-policies/)

Comment: How could you create this whitelist script for a service which we don't have any plugin or module installed or enabled in the website? For example, I have lots of errors coming from refused Facebook connection attempts. But the Facebook Business plugin for Magento 2 is outdated and not compatible with PHP 8.1, which we are currently running. So if I enable the plugin our frontend will break. How to whitelist Facebook without enabling the Facebook Business plugin?